# How do verify my domain for Zoho Mail using AWS Route 53?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53, domain-name, zoho

I purchased trogg.io on AWS Route 53, and am trying to setup Zoho Mail. I'm stuck on the "Verify Domain" step.

After entering a TXT record in my Route 53 DNS, and then clicking "Proceed to TXT Verification" on Zoho, I get a popup that says, "TXT Validation Failed There are no TXT Records found for your domain." Even after waiting several hours, and trying the CNAME method, I get similar failures. What am I missing? Is it because the domain is .io? Or maybe I need some other product/service configured in addition to Route 53?

Here's the DNS record screenshot (I pasted the value that Zoho suggests):

[image: Route 53 TXT Record]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem is not due to Zoho Mail: their pop-up contains the correct explanation.**

The problem is due to an incorrect configuration of Route 53.

Here are the explanations.

The first step that Route 53 needs to do is registering your new domain by contacting the io TLD registry. There are only two registrar IDs used by Route 53: 468 and 81, depending on the TLD (see IANA Registrar IDs public list: 81 is the registrar of a subcontractor of Amazon, and 468 is directly registered to Amazon). Therefore, we can check that your domain has been correctly registered, or not, to the io TLD **registry** by one of the two **registrars** used by AWS:

```
% whois -h whois.nic.io trogg.io | grep 'Registrar IANA ID'
Registrar IANA ID: 81
```

Since the registrar ID found in the output of the whois request is 81, we can conclude that Amazon has certainly done correctly the first step.

The 2nd step that Route 53 needs to do is sending the names of some AWS DNS servers to the registry, to add NS resource records that delegate that domain from the io domain servers to the AWS servers.

We can check this 2nd step with two different tools: `whois` and `dig`.

First, we use whois to look for the DNS records in the database of the io TLD registry:

```
% whois -h whois.nic.io trogg.io | grep 'Name Server'
Name Server: NS-673.AWSDNS-20.NET
Name Server: NS-1685.AWSDNS-18.CO.UK
Name Server: NS-304.AWSDNS-38.COM
Name Server: NS-1263.AWSDNS-29.ORG
```

Secondly, we query some io name server for NS records for your domain:

```
% dig io ns +short | head -1
ns-a3.io.
% dig @ns-a3.io. trogg.io NS | grep trogg.io
; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @ns-a3.io. trogg.io NS
;trogg.io.          IN  NS
trogg.io.       86400   IN  NS  ns-304.awsdns-38.com.
trogg.io.       86400   IN  NS  ns-673.awsdns-20.net.
trogg.io.       86400   IN  NS  ns-1263.awsdns-29.org.
trogg.io.       86400   IN  NS  ns-1685.awsdns-18.co.uk.
```

As expected, the whois database and the io zone contain the same DNS list of four AWS name servers.

**Therefore, we can conclude that the io registry has done its jobs correctly.**

The following step for Route 53 is to host your domain name on these four name servers, with at least one SOA resource record.

So we check for this task:

```
% for ns in ns-304.awsdns-38.com. ns-673.awsdns-20.net. ns-1263.awsdns-29.org. ns-1685.awsdns-18.co.uk.
for> do
for> dig @$ns trogg.io soa | grep ANSWER
for> done
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
```

As you can see, the ANSWER count is 0 for each of the four servers.

Therefore, your domain is not hosted by Route 53 servers.

> What am I missing?

The problem is not due to the io TLD servers nor to the Zoho Mail service.
It is only due to your DNS not being correctly configured on Route 53.

> Is it because the domain is .io?

No, AWS can register any io domain by means of one of its subcontractors, that is named GANDI.

> Or maybe I need some other product/service configured in addition to Route 53?

No, this is only due to your configuration of Route 53. Your problem with Zoho Mail is not due to Zoho Mail.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. Very helpful and I learned a lot! Based on your answer, I have updated my NS records to match those from the `whois -h whois.nic.io trogg.io | grep 'Name Server'` command. I'm curious why Route 53 assigned different NS records from the start. Unfortunately, after running the `for.. do.. dig.. done..` command, the ANSWER still returns `0`. Can you recommend any further actions? I will ask AWS for help, too.

Comment: When you have created the zone, you have clicked on "Create hosted zone". Have you selected "Private hosted zone for Amazon VPC" or "Public Hosted Zone"?

Comment: It is Public Hosted Zone

Comment: I think I need to change my NS records back to what they were, and contact the registrar Gandi SAS to update their values for my domain.

Comment: Can  you a screenshot of your Amazon Route 53 console page?

Comment: I finally got Zoho Mail to verify my domain! The trick was to edit the Name Server (NS) records from the "Registered Domains" section, then click the link "Add or edit name servers". Apparently, if you change the NS records from the "Manage DNS" section, it won't work. There is even a tool tip that states: "If you change the name servers in the NS record for a hosted zone, Route 53 doesn't change the assigned name servers." So the confusing part is that there are TWO spots where you can change NS records, only one of which will have an effect.